# Default cache.addAll cache time?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

This may be a silly question, but my PWA has the index page cached for 6 months, yet after 1 month it did a full refresh (I know this because my PWA uses logged in elements which aren't available after the install so it throws an error when you use it).

This makes me think that `cache.addAll` has a default cache time of 1 month? Is that correct? Can this be extended or is it just a bug in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default items are not updated nor deleted. There's no automatic cache deletion logic anywhere. One thing to note, though, is that the browser itself may purge items from the cache if it so desires. This could happen eg. to free space on the devices.

So either you have a bug somewhere or the browser purged your cache.

More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache

Edit: What abraham in the comments is referring to is this: https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/

Comment: iOS will delete caches for sites that are not visited frequently.